# Correct form for dynamic aggregate initialisation of a struct?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to do something very simple but I'm doing something wrong.

Header file:

```
class Example
{
public:

    typedef struct
    {
        float Position[3];
        float Color[4];
        float TexCoord[2];
    } IndicatorVertex;

    void doSomething();
};
```

.cpp file:

```
void Example::doSomething()
{
    IndicatorVertex *vertices;

    vertices = IndicatorVertex[] {
        {{-1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}}
        {{1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}},
    };
}
```

Upon compilation, I'm getting `Error:(12, 13) unexpected type name 'IndicatorVertex': expected expression`.

(I'm intentionally not using `std::vector` etc; I'm deliberately using C features in a c++11 setting.)

Comment: Why the `typedef struct {..} name` idiom?

Comment: Are you suggesting using a class instead? It's for OpenGL stuff.

Comment: Structures are just classes with default `public` visibility instead.

Comment: Can someone translate any of the above into advice? If it's intended as advice

Comment: That structures are just classes means that suggestion to use a class is irrelevant. And the `typedef struct {..} name` is an idiom (mostly) only useful in C but very rarely so in C++. In C++ it's normal to define named structures in a way similar to classes: `struct name{..};` — instead of your type alias for an unnamed structure. After such definition `name` will already be the name of structure, while in C you'd be required to always type `struct name` after such definition.

Comment: @JBramble: No I'm asking why you use the `typedef struct {..} name` idiom instead of just declaring your type in the usual manner (`struct name {..}`). It can't be for C compatibility because this is itself inside of a `class` definition, which C doesn't support.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No reason for that, I had a brain fart. I've switched to the form you mention, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a dynamic array like you do, you need to define an actual array like

```
IndicatorVertex vertices[] = { ... };
```

If you later need a pointer then remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. So if you, for example, want to call a function which expects a `IndicatorVertex*` argument, just pass in `vertices` and it will still work as expected.

If you want to have different arrays and make `vertices` point to one of them, then you have to define the arrays as shown above, and make `vertices` point to one of them. Like

```
IndicatorVertex vertices1[] = { ... };
IndicatorVertex vertices2[] = { ... };
// ...

IndicatorVertex* vertices = vertices1;

// ...

vertices = vertices2;
```

Comment: Creating a dynamic array with `new IndicatorVertex[] { {....}, ... }` should work though, right?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes it should work (if the size is provided of course), but I don't really see why one would use it instead of a plain array.

Comment: Agreed. I wasn't sure if it the size would be deduced or not :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Isn't that creating the data on the stack though? I would like heap allocation.

Comment: I've tried the `vertices = new IndicatorVertex[] { .. }` formulation and I get error "Expected expression"

Comment: @JBramble Then you need to use `new[]` as explained in the comment by Rakete1111. *However* you ***must*** specify the size. *And* remember to `delete[]` the memory once done with it.

Comment: @JBramble I'm also curious about *why* you don't want to use vectors, or at least smart pointers? What is the use-case? You know that you can easily get a pointer to the data contained in a vector? Using the standard facilities provided by the C++ standard library will make your life as a C++ programmer much easier in the long run.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware that I can access the contiguous array that underlies a std::vector. So will std::vector not add any overhead over using C level stuff?

Comment: @JBramble The C++ standard library was designed to add as little overhead as possible. The only "overhead" of using a vector compared to your pointer is that the vector keeps track of the size and the memory allocated for the vector. If you know the initial size there's a [vector constructor overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which allows you to specify the size, or just use the `std::initializer_list` constructor to set the size and initialize the vector in one go.

Comment: @JBramble (continued...) Practically, you're not going to see any difference in performance or other resource usage from using a vector compared to your pointer.